# Como eu posso usar as funções da OpenCL disponíveis na OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencl

Estou criando um programa em Python, que muitas vezes acaba exigindo mais da CPU e resolvi pesquisar sobre como usar a GPU para o processamento. As bases da OpenCL que encontrei tinham exemplos apenas em C++, e ainda assim, não muito explicativos. Por esses dias descobri que a partir da OpenCV 3.2 tem algumas funções da OpenCL que podem ser usadas diretamente pela cv2.

Gostaria de saber se isso é realmente possível, e se sim, como é a sintaxe para aplicar isso em todo o código, ou em uma função?